# How to set multiple escape letters in mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql

How to set multiple escape letters in MySQL 5.5 . When I set multiple letters ('\",\r,\015\n,\n,\b') in MySQL 5.0.22 it was ok , But in MySQL 5.5.28 is giving error code '**ERROR 1083 (42000): Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual**' 
My Query is as follows ,

```
select ID,MSISDN,IFNULL(TITLE,''),IFNULL(SECONDARY_TITLE,''),IFNULL (NAME,''),IFNULL(ACTIVATION_DATE,''),IFNULL(CREDIT_EXPIRY_DATE,''),
IFNULL(FIRST_VOICE_CALL_DATE,''),IFNULL(FIRST_SMS_DATE,''),IFNULL(FIRST_MMS_DATE,''),
IFNULL(FIRST_WAP_DATE,''),IFNULL(FIRST_TOPUP_DATE,''),IFNULL(TOTAL_USAGE,''),
IFNULL(TOTAL_TOPUP_AMOUNT,''),IFNULL(TOTAL_TOPUP_COUNT,''),IFNULL(LAST_TOPUP_DATE,''),
IFNULL(ACCOUNT_BALANCE,''),IFNULL(TARIFF_PLAN,''),IFNULL(DATE_OF_BIRTH,''),IFNULL(ADDRESS,''),
IFNULL(COUNTRY,''),IFNULL(CITY,''),IFNULL(POSTCODE,''),IFNULL(IC_NUMBER,''),
GENDER,IFNULL(FIXED_LINE_PHONE,''),IFNULL(EMAIL,''),IFNULL(PROFESSION,''),
IFNULL(EMPLOYER_NAME,''),IFNULL(EMPLOYER_ADDRESS,''),IFNULL(EMPLOYER_PHONE_NUMBER,''),
IFNULL(EMPLOYER_FAX_NUMBER,''),IFNULL(SIM_STATE,''),
IFNULL(ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION,'')  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/SUBSCRIBER_PROFILE.txt'  
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\",\\r,\\015\n,\\n,\\b' TERMINATED BY '|' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  FROM  SUBSCRIBER_PROFILE;
```

But When I set only one letter in 'escape by' option, it works

Please help me to solve this issue .
Thanks ,
Dhanushka

Answer (score 0):

The escape character in your case should just be "\" because you're using \ to escape the character.  It isn't asking for a list of sequences that you're going to escape, just the character that lets it know that it is being escaped, in this case the \.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Working with MySQL 5.0.21

```
mysql> select ID,MSISDN,IFNULL(TITLE,''),IFNULL(SECONDARY_TITLE,''),IFNULL(NAME,''),IFNULL(ACTIVATION_DATE,''),IFNULL(CREDIT_EXPIRY_DATE,''), 
    -> IFNULL(FIRST_VOICE_CALL_DATE,'') ,IFNULL(FIRST_SMS_DATE,''),IFNULL(FIRST_MMS_DATE,''),IFNULL(FIRST_WAP_DATE,''),
    -> IFNULL(FIRST_TOPUP_DATE,''),IFNULL(TOTAL_USAGE,''),IFNULL(TOTAL_TOPUP_AMOUNT,''),IFNULL(TOTAL_TOPUP_COUNT,''),
    -> IFNULL(LAST_TOPUP_DATE,''),IFNULL(ACCOUNT_BALANCE,''),IFNULL(TARIFF_PLAN,''), IFNULL(DATE_OF_BIRTH,''),IFNULL(ADDRESS,''),
    -> IFNULL(COUNTRY,''),IFNULL(CITY,''),IFNULL(POSTCODE,''),IFNULL(IC_NUMBER,''), GENDER,IFNULL(FIXED_LINE_PHONE,''),IFNULL(EMAIL,''),
    -> IFNULL(PROFESSION,''),IFNULL(EMPLOYER_NAME,''),IFNULL(EMPLOYER_ADDRESS,''), IFNULL(EMPLOYER_PHONE_NUMBER,''),
    -> IFNULL(EMPLOYER_FAX_NUMBER,''),IFNULL(SIM_STATE,''),IFNULL(ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION,'')  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/SUBSCRIBER_PROFILE.txt' 
    ->  ***FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\",\\r,\\015\n,\\n,\\b'*** TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  FROM  SUBSCRIBER_PROFILE;         
*Query OK, 345812 rows affected (7.77 sec*)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Not working with MySQL 5.5.28

```
mysql> select ID,MSISDN,IFNULL(TITLE,''),IFNULL(SECONDARY_TITLE,''),IFNULL(NAME,''),IFNULL(ACTIVATION_DATE,''),IFNULL(CREDIT_EXPIRY_DATE,''), 
    -> IFNULL(FIRST_VOICE_CALL_DATE,'') ,IFNULL(FIRST_SMS_DATE,''),IFNULL(FIRST_MMS_DATE,''),IFNULL(FIRST_WAP_DATE,''),
    -> IFNULL(FIRST_TOPUP_DATE,''),IFNULL(TOTAL_USAGE,''),IFNULL(TOTAL_TOPUP_AMOUNT,''),IFNULL(TOTAL_TOPUP_COUNT,''),
    -> IFNULL(LAST_TOPUP_DATE,''),IFNULL(ACCOUNT_BALANCE,''),IFNULL(TARIFF_PLAN,''),IFNULL(DATE_OF_BIRTH,''),IFNULL(ADDRESS,''),
    -> IFNULL(COUNTRY,''),IFNULL(CITY,''),IFNULL(POSTCODE,''),IFNULL(IC_NUMBER,''),GENDER,IFNULL(FIXED_LINE_PHONE,''),IFNULL(EMAIL,''),
    -> IFNULL(PROFESSION,''),IFNULL(EMPLOYER_NAME,''),IFNULL(EMPLOYER_ADDRESS,''),IFNULL(EMPLOYER_PHONE_NUMBER,''),
    -> IFNULL(EMPLOYER_FAX_NUMBER,''),IFNULL(SIM_STATE,''),IFNULL(ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION,'')  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/SUBSCRIBER_PROFILE.txt' 
    ->  **FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\",\\r,\\015\n,\\n,\\b'** TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  FROM  SUBSCRIBER_PROFILE;
*ERROR 1083 (42000): Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual*
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response , 
I want to remove all listed escape letters from the file . Actually it is working MySQL 5.0. After I upgrade to MySQL 5.5 getting error